# Autofac Fails to Resolve after App Pool Recycle

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, autofac, ioc-container

I've used Autofac for years and never seen this behavior: after building, the app runs fine. **However**, *after* the app pool is recycled (I tested this by touching the web.config), I get a **DependencyResolutionException**:

`None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Namespace.Controllers.HomeController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters`

HomeController has one dependency, which has other dependencies, etc. But I know it *can* resolve them, because it does before it's recycled. Why on earth would this happen???

I autowire everything like so:

```
public static IContainer GetAutoFacContainer()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    var assembliesToRegister = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .Where(a => a.FullName.StartsWith("Prefix")).ToArray();
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembliesToRegister)
       .AsImplementedInterfaces().AsSelf().PropertiesAutowired().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    return builder.Build();
}
```

Then I use the container for WebAPI *and* MVC Controllers.

```
var autoFacContainer = DependencyRegistrar.GetAutoFacContainer();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(autoFacContainer));
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = 
    new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(autoFacContainer);
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37713188/asp-net-api-di-simple-injector-null-reference-on-iis-pool-recycle

Comment: Also see: http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/faq/iis-restart.html

Comment: Thanks Steven - that solved my problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Steven's comment above, I did find the answer on the other question as well as the Autofac site. Why these never turned up in my research I don't know.

http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/faq/iis-restart.html

**The Solution**

Change `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`

To `BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast<Assembly>()`

**Done!**