# Simple injection not working after forced restart. Need to delete App_Data/Temp/PluginCache and iisreset to make it work

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, umbraco, umbraco7, simple-injector

For my project i am using Simple Injection. Everything works fine. The interfaces are set the website is running.

But when i change something in the web.config or the website is forced to restart then simple injection is not working anymore and there is error on the website.

After a lot of troubleshooting i found the cause of it was the "PluginCache"after deleting that folder and a IIS reset. The website is working and the PluginCache is regenerated.

Does anyone have a solution for it had the same problem? I hope you guys can help me out

Comment: Please add the appropriate details to your question. Exception messages, stack traces and anything that is important to question that might allow this to be reproduced. Please read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37713188/asp-net-api-di-simple-injector-null-reference-on-iis-pool-recycle

Comment: Related: https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/507